# Reading data from json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im having trouble with reading data from json_encode.

i want to read my users info (user_name, x_c0rd, y_cord)

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'inc/odczyt_multi.php',
  data: "",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data == 0) {
      //There r no users
    }
    else {
      for (var id in data) {
        var name = data[id][2];
        var multi_x = data[id][8];
        var multi_y = data[id][9];
        alert(name + multi_x + multi_y);
      }
```

This is my odczyt_multi.php

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id`') or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

And here is a result from odczyt_multi.php

```
[ { "cords" : "",
    "data" : "07.04.13",
    "email" : "ziaja@asdad.pl",
    "id" : "2",
    "kod" : "941140747",
    "pass" : "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6",
    "pozycja_x" : "9",
    "pozycja_y" : "6",
    "punkty_ruchu" : "1720",
    "skin" : "",
    "user" : "Ziaja"
  } ]
```

So there is 1 user in database.

How I can parse that data? Why my alert shout Nan instead of data of this user?

Comment: Are you trying to access individual users based on their ID numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [JSON Website](http://json.org) for more information about reading the data.

If you were planning on having a bunch of info returned in json format.  You could for loop through them.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

  Do stuff with data....

  data[i]['user'] //would return Ziaja
  data[i]['pass'] //would return 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

}
```

I hope that is what you're talking about